# how to achieve run-time polimorphism with enums like java class variables?

Tags: java, enums, run-time-polymorphism

I have developed a project for client's Tractors. Now I have to add same functionality for Combines in that project. So I added a base class called Machine and two child classes `Tractor` and `Combine` extending `Machine`.

So except with some basic changes, my business logic code(i.e. abstract method names in `Machine` class) remained same and code works good for both **Tractor** and **Combine**.

The only issue I'm facing is, I have a **TractorConstant** class with lots of Enums in it which are used all over the project.

And I want to achieve Run-Time Polymorphism with these Enums e.g.

Enum in class **MachineConstant**

```
class MachineConstant{
  public enum Enum195_AreMeterAlert {
     VALUE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, DATE, TIME
  }

  public EnumB1_Enum195_AreMeterAlert getEnum195_AreMeterAlert();
}
```

Enum in class **TractorConstant**

```
class TractorConstant{
  public enum Enum195_AreMeterAlert {
     ACRE_VALUE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, DATE, TIME
  }

 public EnumB1_Enum195_AreMeterAlert getEnum195_AreMeterAlert(){
   return TractorConstant.Enum195_AreMeterAlert;
 }
}
```

And Enum in class **CombineConstant**

```
class CombineConstant{
  public enum Enum195_AreMeterAlert {
     ACRE_VALUE, HARVEST_VALUE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, DATE, TIME
  }

 public EnumB1_Enum195_AreMeterAlert getEnum195_AreMeterAlert(){
   return CombineConstant.Enum195_AreMeterAlert;
 }
}
```

I will have a `MachineConstant`'s reference in my project, and depending upon the machine type selected by user, I will initialize that reference

e.g. `MachineConstant machineConstant = new CombineConstant()`

And in code, I want to call like `machineConstant.getEnum195_AreMeterAlert()`

**But now I get `Expression Expected` error for the line

                `return TractorConstant.Enum195_AreMeterAlert;`**

So how to remove this error and is it possible with enums to achieve run-time polimorphism like this? Or what else I have to do with these enums?

Comment: you didn't really explain what do you mean by `runtime polymorphism`. `polymorphism` is a type system concept and it's majorly referring to a static type construct. your error is because return is expecting a value but all you provide is a class name. you should explain more clearly.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr ok, forget about the runtime polymorphism. By calling 'machineConstant.getEnum195_AreMeterAlert()'  I want to get corresponding enum based upon child class(either Tractor or combine) instance. But I can't return an enum(e.g. EnumB1_Enum195_AreMeterAlert ). That is my problem